# Amount of powder lactase for 1 liter of milk

Tags: lactose-free

Can you please estimate the amount of powder and liquid lactase to add to one liter of milk, as I prefer to use powder lactase?

Comment: This would depend on the concentration of the lactase (in IU units) in the product and the type of milk you are interested in. A brand here has specific instructions for different milk sources, but for 1 litre of cow milk it is "5 drops" for 70-80% conversion in 24h or up to 8-10 drops depending on how much lactose you want to convert and/or how quickly you want it to do it. There's quite a bit of brand variation in amount of lactase per weight as far as I can tel.

Comment: Is there not any kind of instruction on the package?